# Why is this considered an extended initializer list?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

```
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<foo> v(1);
    v[0] = {0, 0, 0};
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this using g++, I get the following warning:

> warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]

As far as I can tell, though, it's just a normal initializer list. The struct is a POD type.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, though I am not positive...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pre C++11 (and possibly C99) you can only initialize a POD at creation, not at arbitrary runtime points, which is what you're attempting here (assignment from an initializer list).

You can make a null_foo though:

```
int main()
{
    const foo null_foo = {0, 0, 0};
    std::vector<foo> v(1);
    v[0] = null_foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not just POD, any aggregate is fine. And such null-defaults look like ideal candidates for globals or statics :-)

Comment: Hmm, alright. A little annoying, but I guess I can live with it.

Comment: I get the same error adding a struct to map with -std=c++98, but it still compiles and runs correctly. I realize this is an old thread, but for the benefit anyone who may read this, it may just be a false-positive warning. What I'd like to know is how to eliminated the warning without using pragmas, or adding an additional line of code.

Answer (score 11):

Brace-initialization for aggregates is only valid during *declaration-initialization*:

```
Foo a = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

It is *not* a way to generate temporaries midway: <s>`some_function(true, {1,2,3}, 'c')`</s>.

C++11 adds *uniform initialization* in which you can indeed write `f(Foo{1,2,3});`.

Comment: @Kenji: The answer from Mark B is clear and complete enough. As he answered first, I've accepted his answer.