# C++0x Initializer Lists and Direct3D 9 Vertex Declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, directx, directx-9

I am wanting to resolve the following warning when concatenating a vertex declaration for use in Direct3D 9.0

```
int elements = 1 + useNormals + useTextures + useColors + 1;
D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 customvertex[elements];
customvertex[0] = POSITIONELEMENT;
int i = 1;
if (useNormals) { customvertex[i] = NORMALELEMENT; i += 1; }
if (useTextures) { customvertex[i] = TEXTUREELEMENT; i += 1; }
if (useColors) { customvertex[i] = COLORELEMENT; i += 1; }
customvertex[i] = D3DDECL_END();
```

The very last line is the one that produces the following warning when compiled with MinGW.

> Graphics_Systems/Direct3D9/DX9model.cpp:340:20: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]

Comment: `customvertex[i] = D3DDECL_END();` are you sure this is the line that givet the warning? What does `D3DDECL_END();` return?

Comment: Yes, line #340 position #20 http://oi43.tinypic.com/1zow8ao.jpg

Comment: Seems like a bug, but I'm not sure. Let's wait for someone more experienced to clarify the issue here.

Comment: According to http://doc.51windows.net/Directx9_SDK/?url=/directx9_sdk/graphics/reference/d3d/macros/d3ddecl_end.htm `D3DDECL_END()` is a macro that expands to `{0xFF,0,D3DDECLTYPE_UNUSED, 0,0,0}`, and is only intended to be used when first _defining_ the array (not to be assigned to an individual element afterwards). Then see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930773/why-is-this-considered-an-extended-initializer-list (Also, you didn't explicitly ask a question.)

Comment: Thank you very much you have resolved my question with your link the code now works with...  `// declared const for C++0x compatibility
 const D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 strideelement = D3DDECL_END();
 customvertex[i] = strideelement;`